# How do I install Bumblebee?

Tags: nvidia, package-management, bumblebee

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and noticed that the battery life drastically lower than it was in Windows due to the fact that Optimus was disabled. After some search I have found the Bumblebee project, but I was not able to install it. The problem is as follows the command `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia` does not work and the output is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee-nvidia
```

I have tried many things, but since I am a new user I might be missing a key point. Previous commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

seem to work without any problems, but "sudo apt-get update" gives the following output,

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I am really confused about the situation and unable to take any action, help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages
```

and then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can then try installing bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have tried it yet it did not work. Do you have any other suggestions?